# Drawing a hollow ring (donut) with width specified in data units (rather than points or pixels)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering if there was a way to draw a ring in matplotlib (i.e., a hollow circle with `facecolor="None"`), except that I want to specify the width of the boundary in data units, rather than pixels / points, so that when I resize the figure, everything stays consistent.

I know I could use some convoluted process of getting the axis dimensions, then converting inches to pixels to points or what have you every time the figure gets resized, but I was wondering if there was a more natural way.

Comment: Show how you would draw a circle with a fixed border in pixels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a good hint from the donut-drawing tutorial in the matplotlib documentation: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/donut.html.

Rather than manually creating a large set of points to draw the circle, you can use [`mpath.Path.circle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path.circle)<sup>1</sup> and [`mpath.Path.make_compound_path`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path.make_compound_path)<sup>1</sup> to create circles approximated by the eight bezier curves that are used by [`mpatches.Circle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html)<sup>2</sup> and similar. This is not as accurate in some cases, but almost always more efficient.

Let's say that you have a center and two radii in mind (in data coordinates):

```
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch

center = (200, 150)
outer = 100
inner = 75
```

You can create a `Path` that has both circles in it:

```
p1 = Path.circle(center, outer)
p2 = Path.circle(center, inner)
```

Eventually you will want to just do

```
donut = PathPatch(Path.make_compound_path(p1, p2))
```

However, before you can do that, notice what the linked docs show about the winding of the paths relative to each-other: if they are wound the same way, the inner circle will be filled the same as the outer. To undo that, you need to reverse the winding of the inner circle.

While this is non-trivial in the general case, for simple paths that start with a `Path.MOVETO` and end with a `Path.CLOSEPOLY` code, you can just reverse the interior portions of the path. I may submit a more general version to matplotlib at some point, in which case I will update this answer:

```
def reverse_simple_path(path):
    vertices = path.vertices.copy()
    codes = path.codes.copy()
    vertices[1:-2] = path.vertices[-3:0:-1]
    codes[1:-1] = path.codes[-2:0:-1]
    return Path(vertices, codes, readonly=path.readonly)
```

This works because segments are stored as a set of control points followed by an endpoint. If you invert everything but the last endpoint, you end up with the correct order for the reversed path.

So now you can do

```
donut = PathPatch(Path.make_compound_path(p1, reverse_simple_path(p2)))
```

Here is a complete example:

```
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch

def reverse_simple_path(path):
    vertices = path.vertices.copy()
    codes = path.codes.copy()
    vertices[1:-2] = path.vertices[-3:0:-1]
    codes[1:-1] = path.codes[-2:0:-1]
    return Path(vertices, codes, readonly=path.readonly)

def make_donut(center, outer, inner):
    p1 = Path.circle(center, outer)
    p2 = reverse_simple_path(Path.circle(center, inner))
    return PathPatch(Path.make_compound_path(p1, p2))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0, 400], [0, 300], 'r')
ax.add_patch(make_donut((200, 150), 100, 75))
```

[image]

The last line could also be written using

```
ax.add_artist(...)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> `mpath` is short for [`matplotlib.path`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/path_api.html).
<sup>2</sup> `mpatches` is short for [`matplotlib.patches`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/patches_api.html).